# How to create the data into database using laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to do the registration form and insert the details into two tables which are the company table and the people table. I face the problems here:

1. How can I get the `comp_id` and add it into my `master_id`? The `comp_id` is `AUTO_INCREMENT` from PHPMYADMIN.
2. How to add the `people_id` into the company table after the people table is created?

company table
| comp_id| people_id| master_id|
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| 7| 112| 7|
| 8| 113| 8|

people table
| people_id| office_id| username|
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| 112| 7| person A|
| 113| 8| person B|

Here is my code, but there is an error and it is unable to create the database.

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {  
  $company = Company::create([
        'people_id' => '["'.$people->person_id.'"]',
        'master_id' => $company->company_id,
    ]);
    
    $people = Person::create([
       'username' => $data['name'],
       'office_id' => $company->comp_id,
     ]);
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

```
protected function create(array $data)
{  
  $company = Company::create([
    'master_id' => $company->company_id,
  ]);

 $people = Person::create([
   'username' => $data['name'],
   'office_id' => $company->comp_id,
 ]);

 $company->people_id = $people->person_id;
 $company->save();
```

}

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have tried the code you give.  Inside $company = Company::create([
    'master_id' => $company->company_id,
  ]);


I will get error undefined $company